# gem list shows knife-windows. But Fails when running the command knife bootstrap windows winrm

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I have Chef Client running in Windows 7 Machine and trying to setup that as node from Chef workstation . Installed Knife-windows using rubygem and gemlist shows the knife-windows (0.8.4)

But the following is failed. 
knife bootstrap windows winrm 10.X.X.X -x UserID -p Password
WARNING: Hostname containing 'windows' specified. Please install 'knife-windows' if you are attempting to bootstrap a Wi
ndows node via WinRM.
Connecting to windows
ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
Check your knife configuration and network settings

Checked WinRm Service and it's running and configured as recommended here https://gist.github.com/jimcroft/3878113

What am i missing?

Comment: What OS is your workstation? On Mac or Linux use `which ruby` to make sure you're using the ruby embedded with Chef. Or windows via powershell `$env:path` and make sure your Chef ruby is there.

Comment: Thanks Dru. I found the issue. It looks like i didn't install Knife-windows in chef-repo instead ran in Ruby folder. By running the following command "chef gem install knife-windows" inside the chef-repo folder fixed the issue.